# How would I kick a user after a certain amount of time of joining the server in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make a bot that kicks a member after a certain amount of time of them joining the server if they dont have a role. this is my code so far. Keep in mind i am using sleep npm plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const db = require('quick.db')
const sleep = require('sleep');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;
    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    member.send("Welcome to the faith garden server! Please verify in the <#685597195789008993> to verify, you can see the questions at <#765603302774669372>")
    sleep.sleep("5")
    if(member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member")) {

    }
    else if(member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Pre-Member")) {
        
    }
    else if(member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Alpha-Member")) {
        
    }
    else if(member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Observer")) {
        
    }
    else {
        member.kick
        member.send("Sorry we had to kick you because you didnt respond soon enough, you can always join back since this is just a temporary kick.")
    }
  });

client.login(token);
```

How i know the code isnt working is because is did node . in the console already, then i joined on an alt, and nothing happened, no dm, no kick after 5 seconds. Nothing. if you know how to fix the bot not doing anything, please let me know. :)

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re trying to solve for here, or what the core of your issue is (a dump of your code alongside a statement that it’s “not doing anything” really isn’t particularly descriptive). Add pertinent context to your question in accordance with the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: i explained in more depth now. @esqew

Comment: Did any errors occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it is clear that you are using discord.js v11. **You can't use djs v11 if you want to listen to the `guildMemberAdd` event.** Discord added an `intents` feature to its API relatively recently that prevents you from reliably listening to guild events without specifically subscribing to them. Discord.js v11 does not support intents, so you must update to discord.js v12.

You need to subscribe to specific intents in order to reliably receive the affiliated events. `guildMemberAdd` is on the [list of events](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents) that will require subscription to an intent.

Here's one possible fix wherever you are defining your client:

```
const intents = ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS"];
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: intents, ws:{intents: intents}});
```

You will also need to enable the below setting for your bot on its discord developers page, since the guild member join event is a *privileged intent*:
[image]

There are possibly portions of your code that need to be changed due to the update to v12.x.x; please look into [what's changed](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) between the versions.

Furthermore, your code is very problematic and unnecessarily over-complicated. Why did you use the node package `sleep` when you could just use a `setTimeout`? Why do you have a ton of empty `if` statements? Furthermore you're not checking if the member has a role, you're doing `member.guild.roles.find()` which is checking whether or not the *guild* has a role. Here are some corrections in your event handler:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    member.send("Welcome to the faith garden server! Please verify in the <#685597195789008993> to verify, you can see the questions at <#765603302774669372>");

    var verifiedRoles = ["Member","Pre-Member","Alpha-Member","Observer"];

    setTimeout(() => {
        if(!member.roles.cache.find(role => verifiedRoles.includes(role.name))) {
            member.send("Sorry we had to kick you because you didnt respond soon enough, you can always join back since this is just a temporary kick.")
            .then(() => {
                member.kick();
            });
        }
    }, 5 * 1000); //The timeout is in ms, convert by multiplying seconds by 1000
});
```

Relevant resources:
[List of intents and associated events](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)
[General info about intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)

Comment: ok it works but, i have a question, to me it looks like the if statement is saying you do have the role, so why is it working when i dont have the role.

Comment: Take a look at the components of the `if` statement. `member.roles.cache.find(condition)` finds a role based on the condition or returns `undefined` if no roles matching the condition were found, and `!` means `NOT` in javascript. By doing `if(!member.roles.cache.find(condition))`, we are essentially saying `if NOT role found`. Without the exclamation point it would be checking if you do have the role, but with the exclamation point it is checking if you do `NOT` have the role.